# seaborn heatmap with conditional formatting

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

i am  using the sns.heatmap() function to create a heatmap from a Pandas DataFrame. I would like to apply a sort of conditional formatting, however, e.g. values <0 will be some shade of red, and values>0 will be some shade of green. is there anyway to impose this conditionality rather than just use the underlying data and colormap directly?

Comment: What would be the difference to using a colormap that goes from red to green?

Comment: if all values were positive, then you would still have red formatting

Comment: Even if you put `center` to  `0`?

Comment: did not see this parameter - thanks!